# pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError: No module __SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB loaded at <pysnmp.smi.builder.MibBuilder object at 0x0418A110>

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pysnmp

I'm just starting out in Python so please bear with me.
I've been trying to find a solution to this error for the last 3 days in google, Stack Overflow, Github, python.org and also snmplabs.com. I have progressed from other errors (thanks in part to the above websites) but this one has me stumped and I cannot seem to resolve it.

I'm running the following versions of stuff:
Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit
python 3.6, pysnmp 4.4.4, pyasn1 0.2.3
and I am using paramiko for ssh and tkinter as a GUI
My project is composed using Visual Studio Code v1.20.1

Basically I have made a python app that logs into a cisco switch and adds a vlan to a trunk, replaces it with another vlan, or removes both vlans

Each time one of these vlan changes is made the script sends an snmp trap to an NMS saying what was just done. The trap is just an OID as follows:

```
def sendTrap(system):
debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('msgproc'))

next(sendNotification(SnmpEngine(),
CommunityData('blahblah'),
UdpTransportTarget(('1.1.1.1', 162)),
ContextData(),
'trap',
# sequence of custom OID-value pairs
[ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0'), OctetString(system))]))
```

Some other stuff happens as well, like the background colour when a change is made, and a timer begins which resets everything back after a predetermined amount of time.

The program works flawlessly when I run it as a python script.

However, when I use cx_freeze to create an exe file of my little app everything works EXCEPT for the snmp trap and I currently get the following traceback error:

```
    2018-02-17 02:17:39,956 pysnmp: running pysnmp version 4.4.4
    2018-02-17 02:17:39,957 pysnmp: debug category 'msgproc' enabled
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\entity\engine.py", line 91, in __init__
        '__SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB', 'snmpEngineMaxMessageSize')
      File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\smi\builder.py", line 409, in importSymbols
        'No module %s loaded at %s' % (modName, self)
    pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError: No module __SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB loaded at pysnmp.smi.builder.MibBuilder object at 0x034C9150
```

The module `__SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB` is located in `C:\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\pysnmp\smi\mibs\instances` and I have this folder included in the setup file as follows (Now THIS is where I think I have gone wrong):

```
    options = {
'build_exe': {
    #'packages':packages,
    'include_files':[
        os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
        os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
        'C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\idna',
        'C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pysnmp\\smi\\mibs',
        'C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pysnmp\\smi\\mibs\\instances'
     ],
},
    }
```

*Please ignore the weird indents as I was trying to get the format correct for presenting it here

Apologies but, although I've done a lot of reading about this over the past few days I'm not totally clued up on things like packages, modules, options and includes so it's all a bit alien to me.

If someone can see where I'm going wrong or if I need to provide more information please let me know. Any assistance would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It feels like the `__SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB.py` file (as well as others in the `instances` directory) has not been included into your .exe file. If this is the case, it is specific to the cx-freeze tool so you should probably ask there. Keep in mind that pysnmp does not explicitly imports these files but loads them at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Ilya
Are you suggesting I redirect this question to a cx_freeze forum?
As pysnmp loads the files at runtime would it work if I copied the contents of the  instances folder into the same directory as the .exe file?
Thanks again.

Comment: I have managed to find the bits in cx_freeze where it appears to be copying the files:
        copying C:\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\pysnmp\smi\mibs\instances\__init__.py -> build\exe.win32-3.6\mibs\instances\__init__.py
copying C:\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\pysnmp\smi\mibs\instances\__PYSNMP-USM-MIB.py -> build\exe.win32-3.6\mibs\instances\__PYSNMP-USM-MIB.py
copying C:\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\pysnmp\smi\mibs\instances\__SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB.py -> build\exe.win32-3.6\mibs\instances\__SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB.py' so I am still not sure where it is going wrong...

Comment: I have now also posted this on https://python-forum.io so if it ends up getting resolved I will advise here too. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some great help from ***snippsat*** at python-forum I finally got this to work.
Essentially cx_freeze wouldn't play nice so we ended up using pyinstaller with a little tweak to the "spec" file ([As detailed at python-forum](https://python-forum.io/Thread-cx-freeze-setup-py-error-No-module-SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB?pid=40082#pid40082)) and everything is now working.